# TFS 2015 - Rename Product Backlog Item & Show field based on another field state

Tags: xml, tfs, tfs-2015

How can I rename the name of the "Product Backlog Item" from the selection on TFS 2015

[image]

Secondly, I have added a new field in my Bug.xml, how can I set this particular field to **only show** when the State: field is "Done"? I have it showing now, but i need it to only be visible when the bug is marked as Done (State).

[image]

Thirdly, how Can i remove options from the drop down in image #1, for example Impediment & Feature specifically.

for #1 and #3 I can possibly use witadmin destroywitd / witadmin renamewitd after some researching, however I'm afraid what knock on effects it may have

Comment: You should really post two questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you could use [`witadmin renamewitd command`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit#rename-a-wit-on-premises-xml) to achieve:

```
witadmin renamewitd /collection:"http://FabrikamPrime:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /p:"team project name" /n:"Product Backlog Item" /new:"New name"
```

For #2, you just add a [WHENNOT](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field#conditional-rules) rule for this custom field like this:

```
<FIELD name="Root Cause" refname="core.resolution" type="String">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="value1" />
          <LISTITEM value="value2" />
          <LISTITEM value="value3" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <WHENNOT field="System.State" value="Done">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOT>
      </FIELD>
```

Using WHENNOT rule, you won't see the RootCause dropdown list until the state changed to `Done`.

For #3, you should first [export the Category file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories) of your team project. Then find the `Hidden Types Category`, add the Impediment under the Hidden Types Category:

```
<CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.HiddenCategory" name="Hidden Types Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Request" />
      ......
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Impediment" />
  </CATEGORY>
```